# Identify missing elements from another dataset per group

Tags: r, merge, group-by, left-join

I have two datasets both containing a common field but would like to retrieve all of the missing elements of one dataset compared to the other one.

My df1 looks like this:

```
Account.ID       Product.ID
1                A
1                B
1                C
1                D
2                A
2                E
2                F
3                B
3                D
```

And my other dataset df2 looks like this:

```
User.ID        Product.ID
X              A
X              B
X              C
Y              A
Y              U
Y              I
Z              B
Z              A
```

My ideal output would be something like this:

```
Account.ID      User.ID       Missing.Products
1               X             Null
1               Y             U
1               Y             I
1               Z             Null
2               X             B
2               X             C
2               Y             U
2               Y             I
2               Z             B
3               X             A
3               X             C
3               Y             A
3               Y             U
3               Y             I
3               Z             A
```

Basically, I would like to retrieve all the Users' Product.IDs that are missing for each Account.IDs.

Here are my inputs sample datasets:

```
df1 <- tibble(Account.ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
          Product.ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "E", "F", "B", "D"))

df2 <- tibble(User.ID = c("X", "X", "X", "Y","Y", "Y", "Z", "Z"), 
          Product.ID = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "U", "I", "B", "A"))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much

The real data is here:

```
structure(list(Account.ID = c(1233248L, 25781287L, 14660627L,
14659269L, 9951007L, 3641831L), Product.ID = c(NA, NA, "01t60000002hNV4AAM",
"01t60000002hNV4AAM", "01t60000002hNV4AAM", "01t60000002hNV4AAM"
)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,
-6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000025a1ef0>)

structure(list(Case.ID = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = 
c("Business Travel Spread Detection Platform",
"Citizens and Doctors Health Check", "Covid-19 Dashboard", "COVID19 Patient 
Information Tracking",
"National Regional Operation Center - Covid-19"), class = "factor"),
Product.ID = c("8001661", "8003103", "8003145", "8004158",
"8004159", "8005365")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000025a1ef0>)
```

Comment: @GregorThomas very sorry if it's not clear. Yes the first row is NULL since Account nº1 has all the Products that User X has. So Account 1 is not missing any Products from User 1. However, Account 1 is missing products U and I compared to User Y

Comment: Hope this is clear

Comment: Your `dput` seems corrupt... with more row names than rows. Shows a warning when I print, crashes R when I try a join.

Comment: Oula yes you're right. Just edited it with the example from Eduardo below

Comment: So, to be clear, you only care about what is missing *from `df1`*. `Product.ID = "D"` is not in `df2`, and it is never identified as missing.

Comment: You're right. Regarding Product.ID = D; No it is not identified as missing since it is not in df2. Account 1 has all the Products that User X has so Account 1 is not missing any Product from User X.   Again thanks a lot for your help and very sorry if this was not clear

Comment: Yeah, just wrapping my head around "Product.ID = D" is missing from `df2`, but we only are identifying things missing from `df1`. It makes sense, the labels just confused me.

Comment: Yes while reading it again I was also confused -_-'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try the following:

- First take `df1` and `group_by(Account.ID)` and `expand` to get all combinations of `Account.ID` and `User.ID`
- Then `left_join(df2)` to add in the required products to identify
- Next, do `anti_join(df1)` to identify which products are missing
- The final `complete` will make sure you have rows available where no products were missing. This assumes the combinations all include X, Y, Z.

**Edit**: To generalize to different `User.ID`, you can substitute `unique(df2$User.ID)` for `c("X", "Y", "Z")`

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  group_by(Account.ID) %>%
  expand(User.ID = c("X", "Y", "Z")) %>%
  left_join(df2) %>%
  anti_join(df1) %>%
  complete(User.ID = c("X", "Y", "Z"))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   Account.ID [3]
   Account.ID User.ID Product.ID
        <dbl> <chr>   <chr>     
 1          1 X       NA        
 2          1 Y       U         
 3          1 Y       I         
 4          1 Z       NA        
 5          2 X       B         
 6          2 X       C         
 7          2 Y       U         
 8          2 Y       I         
 9          2 Z       B         
10          3 X       A         
11          3 X       C         
12          3 Y       A         
13          3 Y       U         
14          3 Y       I         
15          3 Z       A
```

With the Real Data set:

```
df1 <- all_won_subs
df2 <- use_cases_subs
missing_products <- df1 %>%
group_by(Account.ID) %>%
 expand(Case.ID = unique(df2$Case.ID)) %>%
 left_join(df2) %>%
 anti_join(df1) %>%
 complete(Case.ID = unique(df2$Case.ID))
```

Comment: Hi @Ben Thanks for the answer! However, do you know how I could make it more generic? Meaning not having to specify User.ID = c("X", "Y", "Z") but for it to work with any users? Thanks a lot

Comment: I just run the code with your suggestion and got the error: Error: `by` required, because the data sources have no common variables

Comment: When addiding, by="Product.ID" to both the left and anti join I get the following: Error: `by` can't contain join column `Product.ID` which is missing from LHS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210760/discussion-between-ben-and-allanlc).

Comment: The real columns names of df1 are "Account.ID" and "Product.ID", and df2 "Case.ID" and "Product.ID"

Answer (score 0):

Would this be acceptable? I don't know if you specifically need to define your variables as you did. If not, this could be a way:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(Account.ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
              Product.ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "E", "F", "B", "D"))

df2 <- tibble(User.ID = c("X", "X", "X", "Y","Y", "Y", "Z", "Z"), 
              Product.ID = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "U", "I", "B", "A")) 

merged_df <- full_join(df1, df2)
```

Comment: Hi @Eduardp, no unfortunately the full_join will not give me the expected output: Finding the missing products of every account compared to each users